# Working with data using R Rook package

Tags: r, csv, r-rook-package

Does anyone know how to add data table, run some algorithm and save answer using  R Rook application? I have a problem reading data in my application.

Where I should write  `data <- read.csv(file = "BASE_CASE.csv" )`  in Rook.app_2 function or in `write.data.HMTL` function and how? 
Below is a code of my application function:

```
    Rook.app_2 <- function(env) {
    iter <<- iter + 1
    request <- Request$new(env)
    response <- Response$new()
    # I believe that  the problem is in line below
    #I ve got this file in my working direction
    data <- read.csv(file = "BASE_CASE.csv" )
    ## Add functionality to upload CSV-file
    if (!is.null(request$POST())) {
    ## Read data from uploaded CSV-file
    data <- request$POST()[["data"]]
    data <- read.csv(data$tempfile)
    }
    write.initial.HTML(response, iter)
    write.counting.HTML(request, response)
    write.iris.HMTL(request, response, R.server)
    write.data.HMTL(request, response, R.server)
    write.final.HTML(response)
    response$finish()
   }
```

I am using this example for my application: https://www.r-bloggers.com/a-simple-web-application-using-rook/